# Call controller function from HTML dynamically created

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller which have a function called `$scope.removePoster` and another one inside the same controller who create a table calling `$scope.removePoster` like this:

```
for(var i=0; i < 6 && postersNum >= 0; i++){
  ...
  table += '<td align="center">';
  table += '<img width="150" height="175" src="../js/librerias/carousel/images/'+$scope.posters[indexPosters]['image']+'"><br>';
  table += '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="removePoster('+$scope.posters[indexPosters]['id']+')">Delete</button>';
  table += '</td>';
  ...
```

When I add this table in my HTML the button doesn't call this function.

Comment: can you setup a fiddle?

Comment: Strange, angular and rendering html like that? what purpose for you angular lib? :D

Comment: Setup a demo, so it is easier for us to help. Use this to start: http://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/HB7LU/

Comment: +1 to the @Gomatox comment. Is there any reason why the dom element is created in js when angular provides a nice and more elegant way of doing using ng-repeat

Comment: I think the reason is to be cool :D

Comment: Instead of being funny Angular Gurus, you could help the man (that is obviously not aware of `ngRepeat` or the proper way of handling something like this the "Angular way") by pointing to some resources and/or advice !

Comment: Thanks @ExpertSystem. Maybe be an ametur is a sin... The thing is that I wanna do a Dynamic table which when arrives at the 6th column create another row, and I don't know how can I do this with ng-repeat...

Comment: @ExpertSystem Yeap, you are right. Shame on me :)

Comment: @Crisiiii create a fiddle and we will help you.

Comment: This is the complete code of the function, it doesn't work beacuse it's calling a BBDD but I think you can do an idea about I want and how is the correct method to do in AngularJS http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/4144/ @ExpertSystem

Comment: @Crisiiii: Posting all necessary info (e.g. the fact that you want something special to heppen in sixth row, what exactly etc) is crucial in getting the right answer (or any answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are using for something like this:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="poster in posters | limitTo: 6">
        <td align="center">
            Poster {{poster.id}}
            <img width="15" height="18" 
                 ng-src="../js/librerias/carousel/images/{{poster.image}}" />
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" 
                    ng-click="removePoster(poster.id)">
                Delete
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

// Controller:
$scope.posters = [];
$scope.getPosters = function (url) {
    $http.post(url, {'method' : 1}).success(function (data, status) {
        $scope.posters = data;
    });  
};
$scope.removePoster = function (id) {
    $scope.posters.some(function (poster, idx) {
        if (poster.id === id) {
            $scope.posters.splice(idx, 1);
            return true;
        }
    });
};
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/kU4JN/)**.

---

Some highlights:

1. By using `ngRepeat` on the `<tr>` element, we instruct Angular to create as many `tr` elements as necessary based on the content of `posters` (subject to the filtering (see below)).
2. Angular's built-in `limitTo` filter, filter's the `posters` array and makes only the first 6 items available to `ngRepeat`. Conviniently enough, when the content of the `posters` array changes (e.g. after removing an entry), the whole expression gets re-evaluated creating or removing DOM nodes as necessary.

---

**IMPORTANT**

The implementation above is **not** the proper way to handle things in all aspects. It is the cleanest/easiset way to allow you to wrap your head around Angular's way of building a table dynamically.

Specifically, in a "real-world app", you should have a service bring the data from the server and inject the service into the controller to let it gain access to the data.

Comment: Really thanks for your example, I can see the advantage, I think I'm going to use it. Thanks again for your great explanation.